# Reconstructing Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

May I ask is it possible in groovy to transform the map recursively by removing all the key and only keep the value for maps with certain key prefix (e.g. pk-).

Example from this:

```
[
    applications:[
        pk-name-AppA:[name:AppA, keyA1:valueA1Prod, keyA2:valueA2],
        pk-name-AppB:[name:AppB, keyB1:valueB1Prod, keyB2:valueB2],
        otherAppC:[name:AppC, keyA1:valueA1Prod, keyA2:valueA2]
    ]
]
```

to

```
[
    applications:[
        [name:AppA, keyA1:valueA1Prod, keyA2:valueA2],
        [name:AppB, keyB1:valueB1Prod, keyB2:valueB2],
        otherAppC:[name:AppC, keyA1:valueA1Prod, keyA2:valueA2]
    ]
]
```

Comment: No, what you want is NOT a map anymore, and this literal won't even compile. There ALWAYS must be keys present. You cannot remove keys without removing the values

Comment: Maybe you could add what are your plans with this transformation, because as already stated, your "target" is invalid and can not be produced.